# What is a singular inner function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Inner function is a bounded analytic function $\phi$ in the unit disk $D$ such that $|\phi(w)|=1$ almost everywhere on the unit circle $\partial D$.

It makes sense to me that every Blaschke product is an inner function, however I couldn't get the logic behind the definition of the singular inner function. If $\mu$ is a positive singular measure on the unit circle $\partial D$ and
$$
\phi(z)=\exp\left(-\int\frac{w+z}{w-z}d\mu(w)\right)
$$
then $\phi$ is an inner function.

Could you explain me what is the singular inner function and what is a singular measure? What is the logic behind these objects (regarding function factorization)?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "singular measure" is a measure singular to Lebesgue measure.  That is, the measure is supported by a set of Lebesgue measure zero.  (Here we use Lebesgue measure on the circumference of the circle.)

Now we want to show that the boundary value of $|\phi(z)|$ has absolute value $1$ at almost every boundary point.  And it will be helpful to know that almost every boundary point is outside the support of $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you please clarify, why the integrand is $\frac{w+z}{w-z}$?

Comment: And why do we have $\exp$ here?

Comment: Rudin, *Real and Complex Analysis*, Theorem 17.15, p. 370 (2nd edition).  Basically, $\log\,|\phi|$ is harmonic on the disk, so write it as a Poisson integral.